# Canvas clip functio0n

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, clipping

i am trying to make a kids coloring app using HTML canvas where kids can color a particular image. Is it possible clipping the image so that when kids color on canvas..the paint doesn't exceed the image boundaries. The image is a cartoon character.

Comment: You haven't up-voted or accepted a single answer you have been. Upvotes/accepts are the "stimulus" among other things here on SO for people to give answers. http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: oh ok..i new to SO so didnt really know that was necessary. Will do that hence forth